# Angular Component - Component relation

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two components one in shared folder the other in components folder. In the components folder I have a component with a button which when is clicked will execute a function which is located in my services and is a globalFilterService. My problem is that I want that when this button will be clicked the function also executes for this other component which is located in the shared folder. More preciesly in this shared folder component I have a date-picker filter. In the other component I have some other filters, which when the button clicks these filters will return to default state. I want that as well this shared folder component date-picker filter return to the deafult state when the button on the other component is clicked.

Comment: Have you considered using a BehaviorSubject in the service and subscribing from both components?

Comment: Please provide some code or event better a Stackblitz example to help us understanding the topic in detail.

Comment: @Joanmi Yes I think this was my Problem I will try and let you know thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For exchanging information between components without a direct relationship, I recommend reading about BehaviorSubject: [BehaviorSubject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject)

This allows us to subscribe to it and instantiate it with a value. In case we don't want to instantiate it with a value we can use a normal [Subject](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subject).